# Unable to get property 'id' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, extjs, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to create a **Ext.PagingToolbar**, which works perfectly in all major browsers including IE9 and IE 10. But in **IE 8** and below, it ends up with the following **error**.

> Unable to get property 'id' of undefined or null reference

When I traced, I found the error occurs in the following code.

```
var cm = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
    defaults: {
        sortable: true
    },
    columns:
      [
        {
            header: 'Result Set',
            dataIndex: 'result_set_name'
        },
        {
            header: 'Result Date',
            dataIndex: 'result_date',
            xtype: 'datecolumn',
            format: 'm/d/Y',
            dateFormat: 'c'
        },
        {
            header: 'Comments',
            dataIndex: 'comments'
        },
        {
           header: 'Link',
           dataIndex: 'link',
           renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {return '<a href="'+value+'">'+value+'</a>';}
        },
      ]
});
```

But I cannot find the source of issue and what need to be done. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your error is that you end the columns array with a comma which leads to such a error. The IE tries to read a object after the comma which will be undefined

Comment: Oh, thanks for the timely help man. That was the issue and its working fine.

Comment: @sra: Can you post your comment as an answer so that Saravanan can accept it?

Comment: @AdrianLang ok, done :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your error is that you end the columns array with a comma which leads to such a error. The IE tries to read a object after the comma which will be undefined